# how to add a event in fullcalendar in yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2, fullcalendar

i used this code to create a event :

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Url;


$events = array();
  //Testing
  $Event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
  $Event->id = 1;
  $Event->title = 'milad';
  $Event->editable=TRUE;
  $Event->start = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
  $events[] = $Event;

  $Event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
  $Event->id = 2;
  $Event->title = 'Testing';
  $Event->start = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',strtotime('tomorrow 6am'));
  $events[] = $Event;

  ?>

  <?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
      'events'=> $events,
  ));



  ?>


<?= yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget([
      'options' => [
        'lang' => 'fa',
        //... more options to be defined here!
      ],
      'ajaxEvents' => Url::to(['/timetrack/default/jsoncalendar'])
    ]);
?>
```

how to i add a  Drag-n-drop for events!
i cant find a good docs for this work !
this is e extention for fullcalender :

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2fullcalendar/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of events for fullcalender and you can see list of these events in this [link](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) and you can use them in yii2 like this

```
            echo \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget([
                'id' => 'calendar',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'language' => 'fa',
                    'eventLimit' => TRUE,
//                'theme'=>true,
                    'fixedWeekCount' => false,
                'dayClick'=>new \yii\web\JsExpression('function (cellInfo, jsEvent) {console.log(cellInfo);}')
                ],

              'ajaxEvents' => Url::to(['/timetrack/default/jsoncalendar']),                ]);
```

Comment: also if you are persian you can convert fullcalendar to persian calendar just by adding a js and a css.good luck compatriot.

Comment: thanks!how to add a event in this calendar with click?

Comment: as an example `eventDragStart` is an event that we see it in this list http://fullcalendar.io/docs/ ,like this you can use any events like dayClick event. `'dayClick' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('your javascript function'),`

Comment: can i change calendar to jalali?

Comment: I'll send a message to you.maybe at night,maybe tomorrow.It depends on  my codes.